# Is this the correct way to create a lambda from two lists in scheme?

Tags: lambda, scheme

I'm trying to create a lambda from parameters such that `(apply (make-lambda '(a b) '(+ a b)) '(1 2))` returns `3`

My first attempt `(define (make-lambda params func) (lambda params func))` returns `(+ a b)`

This code works but it doesn't feel right to me: `(define (make-lambda params func) (eval (list 'lambda params func)))`

What is the *correct* way of doing this?

Comment: Is this to be used in the scheme environment it's run in or is this a part of a scheme interpreter you are writing? The two would require different answers..

Comment: I'm leaning scheme and want to make sure my solutions aren't ugly.

Comment: You are giving me the impression that you need to make procedures in runtime. `eval` is the only construct that does that. Usually using this, and eval, has large consequences for optimization so if you give us an example how you use this we might come up with a better solution alltogether. Often using lambda and closures with higher order functions are enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to evaluate the list to use it as a procedure, otherwise is just a list of data which happens to have the symbol `lambda` as the first element. This syntax is a bit simpler, but is essentially the same:

```
(define (make-lambda params func)
  (eval `(lambda ,params ,func)))
```

This should work:

```
(apply (make-lambda '(a b) '(+ a b)) '(1 2))
=> 3
```

Alternatively, using a macro as suggested by Leppie:

```
(define-syntax make-lambda
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ args body)
     (lambda args body))))
```

Use it like this:

```
(apply (make-lambda (a b) (+ a b)) '(1 2))
=> 3
```

Comment: If possible, a macro solution would be better.

Comment: @leppie I'm interested in more than just getting it to work. If you have a good solution please post it.

Comment: Cool, wasn't sure if `syntax-rules` stripped the quotes :D

Comment: @JohnK: are your inputs always 'literals' or can they be variable for either or both cases?

Comment: Literals passed to a function that calls make-lambda... So variables. I'm new to macros... How does this make a difference?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez works when following same pattern as syntax-case :D

Answer (score 1):

Because I am bored, and if your scheme supports `syntax-case` :)

```
(define-syntax make-lambda
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x (quote)
      [(_ (quote pars) (quote body))
         #'(lambda pars body)])))
```

PS: Will probably work with `syntax-rules` too (see Óscar López's answer). So I am lazy too.

Example: http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=186

Here is a `syntax-rules` version:

```
(define-syntax make-lambda
  (syntax-rules (quote)
    [(_ (quote pars) (quote body))
      (lambda pars body)]))
```

Example: http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=187

Note: keep in mind, this is exactly what you asking for :D